# Weird Windows 10 boot error that Ubuntu (kind of) fixes

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, ntfs, gparted

I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD. When I try to boot the computer, the loading Windows spinner is (always) stopping after 2 seconds and it freezes my computer.

I found that if I then boot Ubuntu from a USB stick (live preview, not installed) and use the GParted tool to just 'check' the SSD partitions (I think it runs the 'ntfsfix' command), then next time I boot my computer Windows loads correctly.

But if I restart or shut down the computer, the same cycle happens :(

From what I can gather, Windows is setting a flag on my partitions that stops it from loading correctly, and Ubuntu's 'check' command is setting the correct flags.

My question is if I can make the correct flags to be set permanently by Ubuntu? Or does anyone has any idea what is happening?

Comment: Try to run `chkdsk` to check for errors. Be careful with `chkdsk /f` - take backups before running as it can further damage the disk.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the suggestion, I have tried that. First without the /f flag, and in read-only mode it said there are no problems. The same with the /f flag.The computer still still freezes after a few seconds.

Comment: What happens if you boot Windows in Safe mode, shutdown and reboot into Safe mode? Use the [msconfig method](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=39088) which stays on until it's undone.

Comment: @harrymc I have restarted a few times in safe mode (even did a shutdown) and everytime it booted ok, without freezing! After I have disabled safe mode, it froze again.

Answer (score 0):

As booting in Safe Mode fixed the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for it.

To locate the problematic application, you may use the free tool
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system bootup or login
in its "Everything" tab.
You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*

I would suggest turning off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to the startup
program that causes this behavior. Once identified, it might have some setting
that can avoid the problem, or can be left out of startup and only be invoked
when required (verify that once invoked it does not add another startup
entry, but such can again be disabled by Autoruns).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have disabled entries with that program, but this time I was getting a BSOD with the code "Inaccessible boot device" every time I restarted (after about 15 seconds). The trick above with Ubuntu to check the disk wasn't working anymore. So I had to do a clean Windows install. I am now installing apps one by one and restarting the computer to see which one is responsible for the freeze. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: UPDATE: I have installed all my programs, restarting the computer after every install. Each time the computer started ok. Then I left the computer in sleep mode for a couple of hours. When trying to wake it, nothing happened. I restarted the computer and then the freezing started again. I still don't know what is causing it. Any ideas for what I can try?

Comment: Only one: Run [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight. This starts smelling of hardware. Check also the Event Viewer.

Comment: Memtest found no errors.All components in the PC are brand new, this is a recent build. Event Viewer is not showing anything obvious that can point me to a solution, or even identifying the problem.

Comment: Still seems to me like a hardware or driver problem, but no way I can see to diagnose it from far away. Try maybe to disconnect all possible devices to test, reduce RAM sticks etc.