# How can I troubleshoot NVME M.2 performance under Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, performance, nvme

Recently my NVME M.2 drive (system disk) has started performing slowly under windows 10. If I run CrystalDiskMark it shows < 200 MB/s while the computer is fully booted. If however, I boot in safe mode it shows > 3,000 MB/s.

Things I have tried;

1. Replaced the drive with brand new Samsung 970 EVO.
2. Forced the Bios to PCIe3.
3. Removed all possible drivers using MSConfig.
4. Disabled all startup programs using MSConfig.

The computer is an HP I9 with 64 GB of memory just out of warranty.

The computer also has a SATA SSD when I run CrystalDiskMark on it, I get ~350 MB/s sequential reads.
[image]
Today when I run CrystalDiskMark to create the image, it runs at 300 MB/s still 90% slower than it should.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of disk usage from [performance monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10)  - Also, check out the steps in [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/100-disk-usage-on-windows-10/17e3aa7e-4a2a-4927-97bd-bdb2f7dbe04b)

Comment: Some first conclusions: If it works fine in Safe Mode, your hardware is working fine. You do not need to replace it. You do not need to change BIOS/UEFI settings. // I suggest performing a very long benchmark, while it is running you can investigate process CPU usage. Of special interest are processes that hit (100 / CPU count) percent—single-threaded programs maxing out a CPU core.

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1580439/8672) of mine might also relate to your problem.

Comment: Did you install the chipset drivers? Sometimes the Windows generic drivers are not up to date and for NVMe drives could really limit performance.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't truly an answer, but I did solve my problem. The issue appeared to be related to something which was running when the OS was fully loaded.

I had a full backup from copying the system to a new NVME drive. So I took a chance and upgraded to Windows 11 and my disk performance is now > 3,500 MB/s when fully booted.